# Handling timestamp returned from cloud function query in dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using flutter, firestore and google cloud function to build a mobile app.

On the one hand,some of my firestore queries are executed in the client side in dart code something like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection(Collections.cars)
          .where('free', isEqualTo: free)
          .getDocuments();
```

Now this returns a list of Documents and if I have a timestamp field in that document I can call `document.timestamp.toDate()` - in order to convert the Firestore timestamp to a dart DateTime

On the other hand if I do the exact the same in my cloud function and return the result and then I use that result in dart code my timestamp will be of type `HashMap` and contain two fields _seconds and _nanoseconds and I cannot call `.toDate()` on it to convert it to a `DateTime` in dart!

I understand that just from returning the result of the query from a cloud function I'm missing some serializing steps to have the same result as from the normal query, but what I'm wondering is what should I do to have the same behavior?

So can I do something in my nodejs code in cloud function to return the timestamp in a more friendly way, making it easier to convert to DateTime?

I could iterate through the result and convert the timestamp to nodejs Date but I don't think it's the best idea.

Comment: With r"eturn the result in your node code" - you mean - you save the result in firestore again? And after that save - the timestamp is no longer a Timestamp, but a hashMap?

Comment: I mean that my cloud function returns a list of objects and a property of that object is a timestamp!

Comment: Still confusing. What kind of function do you have? http function? So you return the results as json to your dart code? Maybe sharing the cloud function code would make things clearer.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this. I had some methods defined for serializing and deserializing data.
I put the following code, where it was needed:

```
     if (value is Map && value.containsKey("_seconds")) {
        value = Timestamp(value["_seconds"], value["_nanoseconds"]);
        value = value.toDate();
      }
      if (value is Map && value.containsKey("_latitude")) {
        final newPoint = GeoPoint(double.parse(value["_latitude"].toString()),
            double.parse(value["_longitude"].toString()));
        value = newPoint.toLatLng();
      }
```

Just check where this code is needed.